# The process cannot access the file 'image' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web application is built by ASP.NET. It uploads images and save images into database, at mean while it previews the image using ASHX. It works well when I test it on local machine. But when I host it on server, and try to upload same image twice (save as different entry in database), I'll met `The process cannot access the file 'image' because it is being used by another process` error. Since it doesn't tell me which part of my code throw this exception so I don't know where to check. Any suggestion? BTW I do call `dispose()` after use the file. Thanks in advance.

Here is the ASHX file:

```
public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string PLID = "";
            string EMID = "";
            if (context.Request.QueryString["PLID"] != null)
                PLID = (context.Request.QueryString["PLID"]);
            else if (context.Request.QueryString["EMID"] != null)
                EMID = (context.Request.QueryString["EMID"]);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

            if (PLID != string.Empty)
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(ShowEmpImage(PLID));
            else if (EMID != string.Empty)
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(ShowEmImage(EMID));

        }

        public byte[] ShowEmpImage(string PLID)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

            //string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeConnString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sql = "SELECT [ChargingBoxLocationImage] FROM [Parking Lot] WHERE [ID] = @PLID";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLID", PLID);
            connection.Open();
            object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            try
            {
                //return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
                return (byte[])img;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Here is how I preview the image:

```
    protected void btnPreviewImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                bool blnPassesImageValidation = true; // Checks that file is an image, and also that it is < 1 MB

                FileUpload img = (FileUpload)fileUploadLocationPic;
                Byte[] imgByte = null;
                if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
                {
                    string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(img.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
                    if (!chkValidExtension(strFileExtension))
                    {
                        lblFileUploadError.Text += "'" + strFileExtension + "'" + " Format is not allowed. <br>";

                        blnPassesImageValidation = false;
                    }
                    // Create a FILE
                    HttpPostedFile File = fileUploadLocationPic.PostedFile;
                    // Create byte array
                    imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                    // force control to load data
                    File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);

                    if (imgByte.Length / 1024f / 1024f > 1)
                    {
                        lblFileUploadError.Text += "Image size must be less than 1 MB.";
                        blnPassesImageValidation = false;
                    }
                    if (!blnPassesImageValidation) // If the image doesn't pass validation, stop function
                    {
                        PopUpMessage("Error while previewing.");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.SaveAs(MapPath(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File.FileName).ToLower().ToString()));
                        imageEVModel.ImageUrl = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File.FileName).ToLower().ToString();

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PopUpMessage("No Image selected!");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Here is how I save it to database:

```
FileUpload img = (FileUpload)fileUploadLocationPic;
            Byte[] imgByte = null;
            bool blnByteExists = false;

            bool blnPassesImageValidation = true; // Checks that file is an image, and also that it is < 1 MB

            if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
            {
                string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(img.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());

                if (!chkValidExtension(strFileExtension))
                {
                    lblFileUploadError.Text += "'" + strFileExtension + "'" + " Format is not allowed. <br>";
                    blnPassesImageValidation = false;
                }

                // Create a FILE
                HttpPostedFile File = fileUploadLocationPic.PostedFile;
                // Create byte array
                imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                // force control to load data
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
```

At last use UPDATE syntax save `imgByte` to database.

Comment: I think if you loaded the file into memory with the using(stream reader) syntax you might get better results

Comment: Show us the code you have that deals with the image.

Comment: There's only one reason.File is locked from something doing in your procedure.More code please.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Code updated.

Comment: @makemoney2010 I just don't understand why it is totally okay on my local machine but crushed on server.